# How can I redirect and then rewrite url in same file for pretty URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have just been asked to migrate a site from one server to another for a site that I did not build.  They have a lot of links to pages that dont exist.

```
<a href="app/batteries">
```

This is not actually a directory in the site, but there is an app.php file in the root directory. I have gotten it to display the products by redirecting anything to the app/ directory to app.php?app=.  The value of ?app= is dynamic, so any solution would need to be dynamic.  I have simply used the redirect statement in the htaccess file to get it to the app.php page.  Is there a way to get the url back to the pretty url after a redirect?
Any help would be awesome.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ModRewrite instead, for matching a pretty url with regexps, and converting into the url using the app.php.

The rewrite is local to the server, so the visitor sees only pretty urls.

Comment: sporniket, can you give me an example of how to make  the link <a href="domain.com/app/battery redirect to domain.com/app.php?app=battery, but then show the original url of domain.com/app/battery.

Comment: `RewriteRule /app/([0-9a-z]+) /app.php?app=$1` see also http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/

Comment: Sporniket, i appreciate your help.  I may not have explained my issue well.  The original links in the application already point to the pretty URL (domain.com/app/battery).  This does not exist, so I have to redirect that to the app.php and append the value ?app=battery.  This is the page that does all of the processing. Your solution would work if the links in the app already pointed to domain.com/app.php?app=battery.  The problem is I need the the page to redirect to app.php and then rewrite the URL to domain.com/app/battery after the redirect. redirect and rewrite. Any Ideas?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this answer does exactly what you want. It rewrites /app/battery (which doesn't exist) to /app.php?app=battery(which does). And keeps the /app/battery as the URL the user sees.

Comment: When I put that line in my htaccess file. it tells me "The requested URL /app/SCANNER-BATTERIES was not found on this server.". It seems that its not getting the pointer to app.php?app=scanner-batteries

Comment: Okay, got it working. Thanks for all of your help.  This is what worked in the end: ^app/(.*)$ /app.php?app=$1  I guess the only difference was no / in front of app since it was in the root directory and the addition of ^ at beginning and $ at end.  Thanks again.